# Can chartSeries show more than 1 TTR indicator, when chartSeries line is inside an IF-statement?

Tags: r, menu, rstudio, xts, quantmod

I am preparing a menu that is connected to producing a graph where source is xts object and 3 TTR indicators. Seems the "if - statement" that is bundled around the chartSeries line, makes that not all indicators are visible. Currently even if changing the order of the indicators, the result shows only the indicator at the very end of the chartseries line.

Below you see my code that I run in R-Studio.

```
########################################################
# 1. Create a minimal df
########################################################
date <- as.Date(c("2015-10-11", "2016-11-11", "2017-12-11"))
o <- c(1459.60, 1458.47, 1457.71)
c <- c(1458.44, 1457.68, 1458.27)
h <- c(1459.76, 1459.01, 1458.27)
l <- c(1458.08, 1457.52, 1457.70)
v <- c(185, 24080, 9503)
a <- c(185, 24080, 9503)

d3 <- data.frame(date,o,c,h,l,v,a)
colnames(d3)[1:7] <- c('date', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume', 'adjusted')

########################################################
# 2. Produce an xts(x3) based on a df (d3)
########################################################
x3 <- xts(d3[,-1], order.by = d3$date)

########################################################
# 3. Extraction of menu, to select 1 which should
# create a graph with 3 indicators
########################################################
cat("\014")
menu.level.1 <- readline(prompt="Please select just number 1: ")
if (menu.level.1 == 1) {
  print("...create graph")
  chartSeries(x3); addRSI(1); addMACD(2, 1, 1); addBBands(2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems replacing the lines chartSeries, with this line will work:

```
chartSeries(myxts1, TA="addRSI();addMACD();addBBands()")
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought your example worked fine outside of RStudio, but then I noticed the `addMACD` result wasn't being added.

```
library(quantmod)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
if (TRUE) {
  chartSeries(x)
  addRSI()
  addMACD()
  addBBands()
}
```

[image: Not wrapped in plot()]

Then I remembered that can sometimes happen when you use `chartSeries` or `chart_Series` somewhere other than the top level (e.g. in a function, for-loop, etc). The solution is the wrap the `add*` calls in `plot`.

```
if (TRUE) {
  chartSeries(x)
  plot(addRSI())
  plot(addMACD())
  plot(addBBands())
}
```

[image: Wrapped in plot()]